# Azure API Management: How do you add a connection in Authorization or a credential provider in Azure API Management with PowerShell or the Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-api-management

I wanted to create the Authorization or credential provider in Azure API Management using PowerShell or Azure CLI. so, I have used the Azure Management REST API for [AuthorizationProvider - Create or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/authorization-provider/create-or-update?view=rest-apimanagement-2022-08-01&tabs=HTTP) using the [Invoke-AzRestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/invoke-azrestmethod?view=azps-10.4.1) like mentioned below

```
function Add-Authorizaztion {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]$managementURL,
        [string]$subscriptionId,
        [string]$tenantId,
        [string]$environment,
        [string]$tenantName,
        [string]$accessToken
    )

    $apiManagementURL = "$managementURL/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/test-rg-$environment/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apim-test-$environment-xyz/authorizationProviders/testdevhealthcarewsxyz-$($tenantName)?api-version=2022-08-01"
    $body = @"
    {
     "properties":{
        "displayName":"testdevhealthcarewsxyz-$tenantName",
        "identityProvider":"aad",
        "oauth2":{
           "redirectUrl":"https://authorization-manager.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect/apim/apim-test-$environment-xyz",
           "grantTypes":{
              "clientCredentials":{
                 "loginUri":"",
                 "resourceUri":"https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com",
                 "tenantId":"$tenantId"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
"@

    $response = Invoke-Rest -accessToken $accessToken -url $apiManagementURL -body $body -method "PUT"

    return $response
}
```

As expected,Authorization or a credential provider got created in Azure API Management

[image]

However, I don't see any option to add the connection(s)

[image]

Is there a way to add a connection in Authorization or a credential provider in Azure API Management with PowerShell or the Azure CLI

Comment: After workaround on your requirement, I found that there is no relevant `PowerShell or CLI`  commands for connection in credential provider. @One Developer

Answer (score 1):

After a workaround on the requirement, I found that there are no related PowerShell / CLI commands regarding connection in an Azure API management credential manager. Regarding connections in particular, the only possible way to add it is through the Azure Portal interface.

Enabling a `credential provider` is possible with [ARM/Bicep/Terraform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/authorizationproviders?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) templates but its not possible to add a connection in it.

I tried to create a credential provider using bicep code as shown below and was able to achieve it successfully.

```bash
param apiexists string = 'APIWebAppapi10June'
resource apiservice 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2023-03-01-preview' existing = {
  name: apiexists
}
resource apiconnect 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/authorizationProviders@2023-03-01-preview' = {
  name: 'newjprovider'
  parent: apiservice
  properties: {
    displayName: 'newjprovider'
    identityProvider: 'aad'
    oauth2: {
      grantTypes: {
        authorizationCode: {
          clientID: 'xxxx'
        }
        clientCredentials: {
          
        }
      }
      redirectUrl: 'https://authorization-manager.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect/apim/${apiexists}'
    }
  }
}
```

*Output*:

[image]

[image]

Now if I want to add a connection, I need to do it through the Portal itself after deployment.

To do so, go to `Credential provider >> Create a connection` with the required details as shown.

[image]